# Get random position from String based on condition

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have one String variable like this:

```
var data = "FFFTTFFFT"
```

I want to get random position of *'T'* present inside above String for which I am doing like this.

```
for (i in data.indices) {
    if (data [i] == 'T') someList.add(i) 
}
```

then

```
var randPos = someList.random()
```

I am able to do it using loop but I want to do it in idiomatic way in
Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortest solution IMO:

```kotlin
val tIndices = data.mapIndexedNotNull { i, c -> i.takeIf { c == 'T' } }
```